# Get data from eav instead of flat table

Tags: magento2, product-collection, script, flat-catalog

I am trying to get product collection programmatically and product flat table structure is enabled.

I don't want to disable product flat table, this will hurt frontend performance. Just for my script I want to get product collection from EAV structure.

Is it possible to do this? or I need to disable flat table for this?